# Set label on latest element in a branch

Tags: clearcase

I have been working on a branch B1. There are several elements checked in on this branch. Now I want to put, or move if already labelled, label L1 on all latest versions on this branch.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need all elements (files or folders)

- whose one of their versions have a label `LB1`,
- but whose current visible version is *not* labelled `LB1`,
- and then move `LB1` to that visible version.

For that:

```
 cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(LB1)}" \
                       -version "{!lbtype(LB1)}
                -exec "cleartool mklabel –replace REL3 \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Note the difference between:

```
lbtype (label-type-name)
```

> In all cases, TRUE if the object itself is labeled label-type-name. (Because elements and branches cannot have labels, this primitive can be true only for versions.)

```
lbtype_sub (label-type-name):
```

> With elements, TRUE if the element has a version that is labeled label-type-name.

---

The [OP Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990561/paul) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648845/set-label-on-latest-element-in-a-branch#comment84316374_48650887) the following command is working:

```
cleartool find . -cview -elem "lbtype_sub(L1)" -exec "cmd /c cleartool mklabel -rep L1 %CLEARCASE_XPN%"
```

> My config spec must be set to view the latest version in branch `B1`

Comment: After minor modifications I ran this:
    ct find . -cview -elem "lbtype_sub(L1)" -exec "cmd /c cleartool mklabel -rep L1 %CLEARCASE_XPN%"

My config spec must be set to view the latest version in branch B1.

Comment: @Paul Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Guys, this only moves the label if it's already there. You also need a "|| lbtype_sub(L1)" clause in the query to get stuff that never had the label... The -cview  will keep it from finding extra files...

Comment: True. I had to add the label on new elements. But the answer given is good enough for me. Thanks anyway.